# iOS always returning the same transaction id when validating IAP receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm testing In App Purchasing in iOS using 1 SandBox user. When I validate the receipt using Apple server, I get the following response:

```
{"status":0, "environment":"Sandbox", "receipt": 
{"receipt_type":"ProductionSandbox", "adam_id":0, "app_item_id":0, 
"bundle_id":"xxxxxxxxx", "application_version":"0", 
"download_id":0, "version_external_identifier":0, 
"request_date":"2015-05-19 22:04:45 Etc/GMT",  
"request_date_ms":"1432073085427",
"request_date_pst":"2015-05-19 15:04:45 America/Los_Angeles",
"original_purchase_date":"2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT", 
"original_purchase_date_ms":"1375340400000", 
"original_purchase_date_pst":"2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
"original_application_version":"1.0", "in_app":[ {"quantity":"1", 
"product_id":"xxxxxx", "transaction_id":"xxxxxxxxx", 
"original_transaction_id":"xxxxxxxx", "purchase_date":"2015-05-19 18:32:54 Etc/GMT", "purchase_date_ms":"1432060374000", 
"purchase_date_pst":"2015-05-19 11:32:54 America/Los_Angeles", 
"original_purchase_date":"2015-05-19 18:32:54 Etc/GMT", 
"original_purchase_date_ms":"1432060374000",
"original_purchase_date_pst":"2015-05-19 11:32:54 America/Los_Angeles", "is_trial_period":"false"}]}}
```

I tried to make multiple purchases of the same product with the same sandbox user and each time, I get the same response when I validate the receipt. The ONLY fields which are different are `request_date_ms` and `request_date_pst`.

Isn't the Transaction ID supposed to be unique each time??? Is this a bug?

Also the receipt seems to be exactly the same receipt each time. Not sure though as It's a VERY long string. So not sure if it's the same one each time but it sounds so.

The product is consumable so It should have a different transaction id each time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found out why this happens?